# How to write raster in saga format with python

Tags: python, raster, saga

I try to write a raster file in SAGA GIS format (sgrd). My script is work but some information is missing in the final file (i.e output.sgrd).
Here is script :

```
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
import numpy as np

raster = gdal.Open(raster_file)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('SAGA')
driver.Register()
cols = raster.RasterXSize
rows = raster.RasterYSize
band = raster.RasterCount
datatype = raster.GetRasterBand(1).DataType
outDataset = driver.Create(output+'output.sdat', cols, rows, band, datatype)
geoTransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
outDataset.SetGeoTransform(geoTransform)
crs = raster.GetProjection()
outDataset.SetProjection(crs)

raster_out = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=np.uint8)
outBand = outDataset.GetRasterBand(1)
outBand.WriteArray(raster_out)
```

How can I fix my error?

Comment: Hi and welcome! :) We can't help you unless you add more details (which information is missing, why do you expect it) to your question!

Comment: Hi @bugmenot123, thanks for your reply, i have a line on my raster and when i write this line in saga format this line miss.

Comment: Is the line on a new layer or really pixels you added to your original raster?